# Django get_user_model().objects.create() password is not getting hashed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, tdd

I have a test case which first creates a user and then try's to authenticate the created user with Django **authenticate()** method but looks like password is not getting hashed and therefore it fails to retrieve the token... ill share any code related to this section that i think had to do something with the process.

**Custom user model manager**:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """ Creates and saves a new user """

    if not email:
        raise ValueError("Users must have an email address.")

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        **extra_fields
    )

    # Set password this way makes a hashed password
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)

    return user
```

app/**settings.py:**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "core.User" # 'User' is the name of custom user class
```

user/**serializers.py:**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """ Serializer for the users object """

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ["email", "password", "name"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {
                "write_only": True,
                "min_length": 5,
            }
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Create a new user with encrypted password and return it """
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            email=validated_data["email"],
            name=validated_data["name"]
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        print(f"from serializer: {user.password}")
        user.save()

        return user
```

and at last my test case, user/tests/**test_user.py:**

```
  #...
  def test_create_token_for_user(self):
        """ Test that a token is created for the user """
        payload = {
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "password": "testpass"
        }
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(**payload)

        print(user.password) # returns 'testpass' in plain text...

        res = self.client.post(TOKEN_URL, payload)

        self.assertIn("token", res.data)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `create_user` in the test, so:

```
def test_create_token_for_user(self):
    payload = {
        'email': 'test@test.com',
        'password': 'testpass'
    }
    #                     use create_user ↓
    user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**payload)

    print(user.password)
    res = self.client.post(TOKEN_URL, payload)

    self.assertIn('token', res.data)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In the serializer you can also work with `.create_user()`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # …

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
            password=validated_data['password']
        )
        return user
```

Comment: absolutely right, thank you so much.
another question that i used **user.set_password()** in both serializer and manager. is that wrong or maybe will cause any problem in the future?

Comment: @AmirRezazadeh: I would work with `.create_user` in the serializer, and thus pass the password to the serializer. This makes more sense, since it avoids *code duplication*.

Comment: sorry im confused, you mean using .create_user in serializer class? i thought there is only .create() in a serializer class...